# How to combine scope of .order?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, scope

In the controller...

```
@challenges = @user.challenges.last_10 # I'd like to combine into one scope
```

In the model...

```
  scope :accomplished, -> { where(accomplished: true) }
  scope :unaccomplished, -> { where(accomplished: nil) }
  scope :last_10, -> do
    order("deadline DESC").accomplished.limit(10)
    order("deadline DESC").unaccomplished # No Limit on Rendering Unaccomplished Challenges
  end
```

In the view...

```
<% @challenges.each do |challenge| %>
  <%= challenge.name %>
<% end %>
```

How can I list all `unaccomplished` challenges, but limit to the last 10 `accomplished` challenges?

This way I can render something like this...

```
Accomplished Challenge
Accomplished Challenge
Accomplished Challenge
Accomplished Challenge
Accomplished Challenge
Accomplished Challenge
Accomplished Challenge
Accomplished Challenge
Accomplished Challenge
Accomplished Challenge # If User Has 10 or More Accomplished Challenges Stop Here
Unaccomplished Challenge # List All Unaccomplished Challenges
Unaccomplished Challenge... etc...
```

Comment: I'm not in a position to be able to test this but you could try `(order(deadline: :desc).accomplished.limit(10).or(unaccomplished)).reorder(deadline: :desc)`.

Comment: `undefined method 'or'` @SteveTurczyn

Comment: Oh, you're not on version 5 of rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this,

```
scope :accomplished, -> { where(accomplished: true) }
scope :unaccomplished, -> { where(accomplished: nil) }
scope :descending, -> { order('deadline desc') }
scope :last_10, -> { accomplished.limit(10) + unaccomplished }
```

Then in you controller,

```
@user.challenges.descending.last_10
```

Mostly this should work and a point to be noted is that it will return an `Array` and not `Activerecord Array`.

Hope it helps..

Comment: The accomplished are not the most recent accomplished.

Comment: the query i meant here is `@user.challenges.descending.last_10`, then it will right? just to dry it up a bit..

Comment: did you execute that? I did on my console and it returns proper results. Why do you say that it will return 10? correct me if i m missing something

Answer (score 0):

You can ry to do this in raw SQL, but note the boolean test varies by type of database, you might want to look up the correct format for your database... This will also for most databases return an array.

```
query = <<-SQL 
  SELECT * 
  FROM payment_details
  (WHERE accomplished = 1 ORDER BY deadline DESC LIMIT 10) OR
  (WHERE accomplished <> 0) 
  ORDER BY deadline DESC 
SQL

result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)
```